# May we write 4 when dealing with a ring that may not have a 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question where I am asked to show that if for a ring $R$ and $\forall x\in R$ we have $x^2=x$ then $x+x=0$

I have shown this as follows:

$(x+x)^2=x^2+x^2+x^2+x^2=x+x+x+x$ (by distributivity then by $x^2=x$)

Or

$(x+x)^2=x+x$ (by $x^2=x$)

Thus $x+x+x+x=x+x\implies x+x=0$ as required.

I am quite happy that when I write 1 I mean the multiplicative identity, and 0 the additive, but it'd be much nicer if I could use 4s and 2s. Then I could write:

$(x+x)^2=(2x)^2=4x^2=4x$ by $x^2=x$ (BUT then I could argue 4=2 by the same rule, if 4x denotes 4 in the ring multiplied by x in the ring....)

I am pretty sure (read certain but cannot prove) that this ring has just 2 elements, the identities 1 and 0, so it'd be wrong to say a 4 exists and that I am using it. However if I use $4x$ to denote $x+x+x+x$ rather than the product of $4\in R$ times $x\in R$ it's not fine.

**So my question is what are the rules on using numbers when manipulating rings?**

(By the way, a ring where the identities are the same element (that is 0=1) has one element, but the concept of 1 and 0 exists, If that is the case there is without a doubt not a 2 in the ring, so turning $x+x$ to $2x$ would be wrong if interpreted as $2\in R$ times $x\in R$ -this is what I've stated above, but in a ring we know not to contain numbers)

Comment: In any ring, $4$ is defined to be $1+1+1+1$. In the integers, $2$ and $4$ are different numbers, but in your ring $2$ and $4$ are the same number. This is similar to $21/30$ and $7/10$ being the same number in the rationals. -- Another way of understanding the same notation is to view rings as $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras. Then $4x$ means $4\in \mathbb{Z}$ times $x \in R$, which is defined to be $x+x+x+x$. If you are bothered by 4 not "really" being in your ring, then you can use this Z-algebra idea. The first view of $4$ is then written as $4\cdot 1$, with $4$ the integer and $1 \in R$.

Comment: Note that both of the answers tell you how the expression $nx$ can be interpreted for $n \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \in R$, without assuming that $n$ has any meaning as an element of $R$. However, it seems to me that you are working within the concept of unital rings, in which you have a multiplicative identity $1$. If you assume $R$ is unital, then there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z \to R$ carrying $1 \in \mathbb Z$ to $1 \in R$, and it is through this ring homomorphism that $n \in \mathbb Z$ can be interpreted to represent an element of $R$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein there is one part I don't quite get, what if $4\in R$, and I write $4x$ meaning the operation of "multiplication" of 4 and x? How will I know which 4 I mean (x+x+x+x) or 4*x - I'm not sure it'll matter, but I don't want to ignore this (potential) issue.

Comment: It won't matter; $4\cdot x = (1+1+1+1)\cdot x = 1\cdot x+1\cdot x+1\cdot x+1\cdot x = x+x+x+x$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein evidently and certainly not in this case, but in all rings I might consider? Actually... I see what you mean.

Comment: This is true in any unital ring.

Answer (score 3):

Rings are generally regarded as "$\mathbb{Z}$-modules".  That is, it's okay to use integers as coefficients, even if the integers are not themselves (necessarily) members of the ring.  For any $x \in R$, we define
$$
nx = \overbrace{x + \cdots + x}^n
$$
One may show that, in general, $(m+n)x = mx + nx$, that $m(x + y) = mx + my$, that $m(nx) = (mn)x$, and that $1x = x$ under this definiton.  From there, we may deduce that integer multiplication obeys all the usual rules, so that we indeed have
$$
(2x)^2 = 2^2x^2 = 4x^2
$$

Comment: But is it wrong to see $2^2$ and say $2^2=2$ this is why I thought it was ambiguous/bad, because surely this tries to impose the structure of the ring onto Z, which may be dangerous (I'm confident enough to assert it is safe)

Comment: Don't say $2^2 = 2$, say that for all $x \in R: 2^2x = 2x$.

Comment: The real idea is that "in the context of this particular ring, the action denoted by $2^2$ is identical to that denoted by $2$".